# Can I show a form in a DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll

I would like to show a form (modally) in a COM DLL (as a user prompt). The DLL methods will eventually be invoked by some JavaScript in the browser (yeuck, but not my choice & can't be changed).

However, when I invoke the DLL method from my Delphi test program, I get an access violation.

Can I do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sure, show us what you got...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no problem at all. Perhaps you are relying on auto-create for your forms. That only happens in an EXE project. If my guess is correct you'll have a global variable of type TMyForm that is never initialized.

You need something like this:

```
var
  MyForm: TMyForm;//local variable
....
MyForm := TMyForm.Create(nil);
try 
  MyForm.ShowModal;
finally
  MyForm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: @Marjan Why? That can only be done by calling Application.CreateForm. I never do so in my DLL. I see no need to do so.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I believe you needed to set Application.Handle to the handle of the main application, because that is the handle that recieves application messages. I think it's also the handle that is notified if forms need to be locked when another form is shown modal. So that may be needed if you need to show the DLL form modally. But I would test first, before implementing a bunch of tricks you may not need.

Comment: @GolezTrol: That's it. Thanks for clearing the mist. Deleting my previous comments. And I agree with your advice to test first!

Comment: If the host app has a main form then sure, assign its handle to `Application.Handle`. But if not, then you can do nothing.